# video is working in chrome and IE9 but not working inIE8?

Tags: jquery

this is what i put in `<head>` tag

```
<code><script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaelementplayer.css" /></code>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in console???

Comment: no, its just not showing video in IE8 (XP)

Comment: i put above code in head tag.Following this link http://mediaelementjs.com/#installation

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 don't support HTML 5 video tag...

Comment: what i need to do to run video in older browers (IE6-IE8)??